# REST API with image processing?

Tags: python, django, rest, api-design

This may not be a great question but I am new to API's and REST API's. I understand what API's do, and have a general understanding of REST API's (GET, POST, SET, etc).

What I'm confused about is in almost all examples I've seen, the REST API's are database related (query data, update data, insert new data, etc). So I was wondering, if I wanted to create an API where I can send an image, process it in the backend (in Python) and return some image and annotations, is this still considered a REST API, and are there any conventions/advice for this kind of thing?

What would be the best way to go about doing this? For context I get the image from a React Native frontend and want to do the image processing in python (I understand this is still very vague).

Comment: The definitions are fuzzy, but a REST API usually does involve manipulating objects that are stored on the server.  Partly, REST is about a consistent URL design.  If you're just taking objects, mucking with them and returning them, then it's not really an API.  It's just a single URL.

Comment: What do you think would be the best way to go about doing this? For context I get the image from a react native front end and want to do the image processing in python (I understand this is still very vague)

Comment: "Best way" of what?  If this is just a web service used by a front-end, then you do whatever makes sense.  Maybe you should sketch out some scenarios, and see what URLs make sense to you;  You could do `mysite.com/adjust.py?brightness=+10&saturation=-5`.  Or separate as `mysite.com/adjust/brightness?v=+10`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple litmus test: if you can imagine it as a web site, then it can be a REST API.

REST, after all, is the [architectural style](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/software_arch.htm#sec_1_5) of the world wide web, which is to say it is the collection of architectural constraints that ensure that the web has the properties it has.

The usual approach is to start with HTTP, which is an application protocol for [transferring documents over a network](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=3m8s).  So you create a facade, where people get information from you by retrieving documents, and send information to you by forwarding documents, and then behind that facade you do the real work.

> if I wanted to create an API where I can send an image, process it in the backend (in Python) and return some image and annotations, is this still considered a REST API

You could build a REST API to do that.  Hint: we already have things HTML forms, and input controls that afford file uploads, and form processing rules that can embed a file into an HTTP request, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can absolutely do that, you necessary have interacted with the database for it to be an API, For instance, you can create a simple function that gets

```python
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)


def do_image_processing(image):
  print("doing some image processing ")
  return "Response"
  
  
@app.route('/')
def index():
  image = request.files.get('image')
  response = do_image_processing(image)
  return response
```

called when you're API receives an image, do some processing, and then return feedback to the User

You can also Take a look here at an [old project](https://github.com/Kalebu/Mobilenet-object-detection-api/blob/master/api.py) at Github which is an API that receives an image and use a mobile object to recommend tags based on image hope that's relevant to your task